# Merging two nodes running endlessly in Neo4j

Tags: merge, neo4j

I am new to neo4j, I am trying to merge two nodes as mentioned below:

> MATCH (n:node2) MERGE (p:node1 {p.id:n.id}) ON CREATE SET
> p.column1=n.column1,p.column2=n.column2,
> p.column3=n.column3,p.column4=n.column4,p.column5=n.column5,p.column6=n.column6,
> p.column7=n.column7 ON MATCH SET
> p.column1=n.column1,p.column2=n.column2,
> p.column3=n.column3,p.column4=n.column4,p.column5=n.column5,p.column6=n.column6,
> p.column7=n.column7;

Node1 contains 2 million nodes with 8 properties and node2 contains 184000 nodes with 8 properties.

I am trying to merge node2 records with node1, but this merge runs endlessly. Is there any way to run this merge command in less time?

Answer (score 2):

Well to speed up the `MERGE`, you should create an index on `node1` label nodes for the key `id`. Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX id_index IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:node1) ON (n.id)
```

Secondly, your query can be simplified a bit, instead of manually setting each property like this, both in `ON CREATE` and `ON MERGE`:

```
MATCH (n:node2) 
MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id}) 
ON CREATE SET p.column1=n.column1,p.column2=n.column2, p.column3=n.column3,
p.column4=n.column4,p.column5=n.column5,p.column6=n.column6, p.column7=n.column7 
ON MATCH SET p.column1=n.column1,p.column2=n.column2, 
p.column3=n.column3,p.column4=n.column4,
p.column5=n.column5,p.column6=n.column6, p.column7=n.column7;
```

You can simply do this:

```
MATCH (n:node2) 
MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id}) 
SET p += properties(n)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works a charm. But instead of merging two nodes, I am trying to fetch node2 data directly from a snowflake table like below: WITH "jdbc:snowflake://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com:xxx/?user=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&db=xxxx&warehouse=xxxx&schema=xxxx" as url CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"TABLE1") YIELD n MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id}) SET p += properties(n); It's working perfectly and 2 million rows merged within 4 mins

Comment: But, When I tried to implement the batch load I am getting the below error. WITH "jdbc:snowflake://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com:xxx/?user=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&db=xxxx&warehouse=xxxx&schema=xxxx" as url CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"TABLE1") YIELD n call apoc.periodic.iterate("WITH n MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id}) SET p += properties(n)",{batchSize:10000}); Error: Unknown procedure output: ROW (line 1, column 279 (offset: 278)).

Comment: Can you add the complete batching query you are trying in the question, along with the error? Thanks.

Comment: This is the query:

WITH "jdbc:snowflake://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com:xxx/?user=xxxxxxxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxxxxx&db=xxxx&warehouse=xxxx&schema=xxxx" as url CALL apoc.load.jdbc(url,"TABLE1") YIELD n call apoc.periodic.iterate("WITH n MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id}) SET p += properties(n)",{batchSize:10000});

Comment: Error: Unknown procedure output: ROW (line 1, column 279 (offset: 278)).

Comment: Isn't 4 minutes quick enough?

Answer (score 2):

You are copying node2 into node1 when node2.id does not exists in node1 and update column values (properties) in node1 when found in node2.  In short, you need to find node2 not found in node1 then do the merge.

```
MATCH (n:node2) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( (:node1 {id: n.id})--() ) 
WITH n
MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id})    //I fix a typo error. It should be id and not p.id
SET p += properties(n)
```

If the execution time is still long running, install APOC function and run below. It will do the merge by batch of 10k.

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "
    MATCH (n:node2) WHERE NOT EXISTS( (:node1 {id: n.id})--() ) 
    RETURN n
    ",
    "
    WITH n
    MERGE (p:node1 {id:n.id})
    SET p += properties(n)
    ",
    {batchSize:10000}
)​
```