# Optimize Neo4j relationships creation

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have definitions (in code/files) for ~400k nodes and ~500k relationships. I need to put this on a Neo4j database. For this, I programmatically build a query to create each node with a unique id (UUID) field in it's properties.

```
CREATE (:MyNode {UUID: "aaaa"});
CREATE (:MyNode {UUID: "bbbb"});
...
```

After creating all nodes in DB I create relations with a query that looks like:

```
MATCH (a {UUID: "aaaa"}), (b {UUID: "bbbb"})
CREATE (a)-[:MyRelation]->(b);

MATCH (c {UUID: "cccc"}), (d {UUID: "dddd"})
CREATE (c)-[:MyRelation]->(d);

...
```

So running this requires ~500k MATCH statements that run over ~400k nodes. Is there a better approach to optimize this?

NOTE: unifying node and relationships creation.on same query to take advantage of variables is not practical. The query is too large.

My raw data is formated like this (In case you want to test):

```json
{
  "nodes": [
    { "UUID": "0001" },
    { "UUID": "0002" },
    { "UUID": "0003" },
    { "UUID": "0004" },
    { "UUID": "0005" }
  ],
  "relationships": [
    { "uuid_A": "0001", "uuid_B": "0002", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0001", "uuid_B": "0003", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0002", "uuid_B": "0003", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0002", "uuid_B": "0004", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0003", "uuid_B": "0004", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0003", "uuid_B": "0005", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0004", "uuid_B": "0005", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0004", "uuid_B": "0001", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0005", "uuid_B": "0001", "label": "related_to" },
    { "uuid_A": "0005", "uuid_B": "0002", "label": "related_to" }

  ]
}
```

Comment: I actually use UNWIND to build the queries. But I understand matches are still done

Comment: You should create an index on `UUID` property of your nodes, to speed up the `MATCH` lookups. To create an index, you can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801915/merging-two-nodes-running-endlessly-in-neo4j/73803028#73803028

Comment: See [docs on indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes-for-search-performance/).

Comment: @CharchitKapoor index did the trick. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed recommendation.

1. Create 2 CSV input files (since the data will be processed in separate queries, and to make the files more compact):

   - `nodes.csv` for the `MyNode` properties (which in your case is just a `UUID`). For example:

     ```
     uuid
     0001
     0002
     0003
     0004
     0005
     ```
   - `rels.csv` for the `MyRelation` data. For example:

     ```
     from,to,type
     0001,0002,related_to
     0001,0003,related_to
     0002,0003,related_to
     0002,0004,related_to
     0003,0004,related_to
     0003,0005,related_to
     0004,0005,related_to
     0004,0001,related_to
     0005,0001,related_to
     0005,0002,related_to
     ```
2. Create a [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/constraints/) on `:MyNode(uuid)` to enforce that the UUIDs are indeed unique. This also automatically creates an index on `:MyNode(uuid)` for you. Having an index will be important for quickly finding nodes by UUID, which we will need to do when ingesting relationships below.

   ```
   CREATE CONSTRAINT MyNode_uuid FOR (m:MyNode) REQUIRE m.uuid IS UNIQUE
   ```
3. Ingest the data in 2 queries using [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/load-csv/).

   - First ingest the nodes. I assume your DB has no `MyNode` nodes to start with, so we can use `CREATE` instead of the slower `MERGE`. Also, to avoid running out of memory and to improve performance, we commit after processing every 50K nodes (you can play with the number to see what works better for you). When using `IN TRANSACTIONS` in the neo4j Browser, you need to prepend `:auto` to the front of the query (to see some docs on this, enter `:help auto` in the Browser).

     ```
     LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes.csv" AS row
     CALL {
       WITH row
       CREATE (:MyNode {uuid: row.uuid})
     } IN TRANSACTIONS OF 50000 ROWS
     ```
   - Then ingest the relationships. Again, you can tweak the 50K value.  In order to use the index we created earlier, the `MATCH` clause must specify the indexed node label and property. We use the APOC function [apoc.create.relationship](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.relationship/) to dynamically specify the relationship type.

     ```
     LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///rels.csv" AS row
     CALL {
       WITH row
       MATCH (a:MyNode {uuid: row.from}), (b:MyNode {uuid: row.to})
       CALL apoc.create.relationship(a, row.type, NULL, b) YIELD rel
       // Need to RETURN to conform with Cypher syntax.
       // But return aggregated value so subquery only returns 1 row, which
       // will not affect the number of rows in the enclosing query.
       RETURN COUNT(*) AS cnt
     } IN TRANSACTIONS OF 50000 ROWS
     RETURN SUM(cnt) AS num_rels_added
     ```

Comment: Ok, the constraint (index) is all I need since I already have the data in suitable format. But this is an EXCELLENT answer.